# Iterate json data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Following JSON data comes from php,

[image: Json format]

I have tried following code. But console displays `undefined` error.

```
jQuery.each(result.address, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj.city);
});
```

EDIT : Also it's not working and throwing undefined error.

```
jQuery.each(result.address, function(obj) {
  console.log(obj[0].city);
});
```

It is working : `console.log(result.address.address1.city);`. But in this case address1 is not fixed. eg. `result.address.xyz.city, result.address.abc.city`

Comment: There's no `city` property directly in `result.address`.

Comment: That is my mistake. There are multiple addresses within 'address'. Each address have city and other values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling city on each address, while cities are inside addressX inside address. Try:

```
jQuery.each(result.address, function(key, val) {
    console.log(val.city);
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/useq4xzg/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < result.address.length; i++) {
    console.log(result.address[i].city);
}
```

I'm not sure if jquery.each works in this case.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Why? I just try to help...

Comment: I don't get why everyone is getting down-voted in this question. It's unfair, unwarranted, and harmful to the nature of the SO community. I gave you and the other answer an up-vote because you **did** answer the question.

Comment: @pabgaran ,Sorry it doesn't work , https://jsfiddle.net/useq4xzg/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
 var dictionary = {
        "12Jan2013": [{
            "id": "0",
            "name": "ABC"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "DEF"
        }],
        "13Jan2013": [{
            "id": "0",
            "name": "PQR"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "xyz"
        }]
    };

for (var i in dictionary) {
    dictionary[i].forEach(function(elem, index) {
        console.log(elem, index);
    });
}
```

**Output**

```
Object {id: "0", name: "ABC"} 0 
Object {id: "1", name: "DEF"} 1 
Object {id: "0", name: "PQR"} 0 
Object {id: "1", name: "xyz"} 1
```